# Airflow AWS ECS operator not fetching Cloudwatch logs when used with firelens

Tags: airflow, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, fluentd

I am using the Airflow EcsOperator to run AWS ECS Tasks. As part of this, I am using a custom fluentbit container that is setup to log the  container logs  to Cloudwatch and AWS Open Search. The logging to both destinations work fine. However, I noticed that the Cloudwatch log groups are getting generated in the format {awslogs_stream_prefix}-{ecs_task_id}. Braces are added to just show the two parts separately, the actual prefix is of the form "ecsprime-generator-container-firelens-977be157d3be4614a84537cd081152d7" where the string starting with 977 is the Task Id. Unfortunately, Airflow code that reads Cloudwatch logs expects the log group name to be in the format {awslogs_stream_prefix}/{ecs_task_id}. Due to this, I am not able to have the Airflow EcsOperator display the corresponding Cloudwatch logs.

Are there any workarounds to address this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Fluentbit `cloudwatch` plugin to achieve this. Not that there's a new, better plugin (`cloudwatch_logs`), but I did not have success finding out how to grab the ECS task ID from it.

```
@INCLUDE /fluent-bit/configs/parse-json.conf

[OUTPUT]
    Name                     cloudwatch
    Match                    *
    region                   eu-west-1
    log_group_name           ecs/airflow
    log_stream_name          {awslogs_stream_prefix}/$(ecs_task_id)
    auto_create_group        false
```